# Regex Expression for this conditon

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex where I count syllabes for word . What counts as syllable is any word that has aeiou but a word ending in e that is not a syllable.Any consecutive vowels in 1 syllable .

e.g.

```
this (1 syllable)
Where (1 syllable) 
why (1 syllable)
seeeenteences (3 syllable)
whyyyye (1 syllable)
```

THis is what I have so far In `java`

```
[AEIOYUaeioyu]+
```

this accounts for syllables but does not consider to exclude syllable for words ending with `e` . Any thoughts by anyone on this.

Comment: My thoughts are that it will be very difficult to come up with a one size fits all regex to detect syllables in English language words.  The reason is that English grammar is very irregular and I would expect many edge cases.

Comment: Could you elaborate it some more ?

Comment: Can you tell number of syllables in `aaii`? are `aa` and `ii` treated as different?

Comment: How many syllables in `vitae`? `rapee`?

Comment: "Skiing" has two syllables

Comment: @AdrianShum vitae - 2 (excluding last e) , rapee -2 (excluding the last e only).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this is not actual definition of syllable but only a working version to encourage us to write a regex and not copy from net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming for case like `aaii` :- `aa` and `ii` are treated as two different syllable, this seems to work

```
(?=([AIOUYaiouy]))(\\1+)|([Ee]+)(?<![Ee]$)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pK4oZ2/3)**

*Java Code*

```
String pattern = "(?=([AIOUYaiouy]))(\\1+)|([Ee]+)(?<![Ee]$)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
int cnt = 0;

while (m.find()) {
   cnt++;
}

System.out.println(cnt);
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/kkVZp1)**

For counting the syllables, you can use this **[source](http://www.howmanysyllables.com/)**

**NOTE**

This code is written just to meet the requirement of `OP` as mentioned in question.

Comment: "Skiing" has two syllables

Comment: @Bohemian According to `OP's` rule it should be `1`..`Any consecutive vowels in 1 syllable`

Comment: @rock321987 is correct any consecutive syllables are termed as one syllable. This is not a true definition of syllable but the given definition to help us write regex

Comment: @Praveen If you need any explanation feel free to ask and don't forget to accept..:)

Comment: @rock321987 sure I will . Let me go home and implement to confirm this works and then will go ahead and accept it

Comment: @rock321987 can you please explain me a bit what the regex does. as far as I could infer you are lookig ahead to find set of either AIOUY and the 1+ denotes one more instances of this essentilly making it  [AIOUYaeiou]+ . But this does not work so I am sure I am getting something wrong here .

Comment: @Praveen I will add an explanation

Comment: also I think this one failed. 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, qui ex choro quodsi moderatius, nam dolores explicari forensibus ad.

Comment: @Praveen `[AIOUYaeiou]+` denotes any combination from these characters..For this `aio` is valid..I am trying to find `repeated characters` using `\\1`..It means what was previously matched, repeat it..So I am trying to find (sub)string like `aaaa`

Comment: @Praveen is `Lorem`, `ipsum` etc. are different string or a sentence?

Comment: @Praveen the string used in my code should not contain space

Comment: I am passing one word at a time to cound for syllable . So it should not containt spaces . The way I filter word is [A-Za-z]+

Comment: @Praveen the only solution that I can think of is via using some `Java methods` but not with single `regex`..sorry to let you down..if I will be able to do via a regex I will update you

Comment: @rock321987 Yeah I was looking at solution and it basically looped to determine the syllables and it stated that regex might  not solve everything . Anyways thanks for all your help and effort.

Answer (score 0):

[AEIOYUaeioyu]+(?=\w) this will check to see if there is any character following the vowels

Answer (score 0):

With your definition of syllables, I think it is less related to how the regex is, but more about how you make use of regex to get the result.

For example, simply by removing the ending `e`, and append a dummy consonant, you get the result by a simple split:

(This code simplify the case a bit by assuming all-lowercase)

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        syllables("this");
        syllables("where");
        syllables("seeeetennnces");
        syllables("why");
    }

    public static int syllables(String s) {
        int i = s.replaceAll("e$", "").replaceAll("$","x").split("[aeiouy]+").length - 1;
        System.out.println(s + " " + i);
        return i;
    }
}
```

Above code gives

```
this 1
where 1
seeeetennnces 3
why 1
```

(Though I wonder if your definition of syllables is correct)

Comment: This as you said is to help understand regex. This is not the correct definition of syllables but being a novie they "dummed" in down a bit.

Also not a fan of replacing last e since I am will be using this in other places and the whole point is to write a regex than will satisfy the situation